# D3 fisheye on a force graph with markers

Tags: d3.js, path, force-layout, markers, fisheye

I love the new fisheye plug in (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) but want to get it working on a force graph that uses paths and markers rather than lines. I am new to D3 and so far combining the markers demo, with the fisheye demo has defeated me, I wondered if anyone had been successful and could point me in the right direction.

Cheers Ben

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: Yes: used paths instead of edges, and then updated the fish eye function so that the line length took into account the changing size of the nodes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vis.on("mousemove", function() {
        if (rmbMenuHidden)
        {
            fisheye.center(d3.mouse(this));

```
        node
            .each(function(d) { d.display = fisheye(d); })
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.display.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.display.y; })
            .attr("r", function(d) {  d.display.r=d.display.z * 10; return d.display.r;});

        path.attr("d", function(d) {

            var dx = d.t.display.x - d.s.display.x;
            var dy = d.t.display.y - d.s.display.y;

            var h= Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            var htr = h-d.t.display.r-d.edgeWidth-1;
            var cos=dx/h;
            var sin=dy/h;

            var dxt = cos*htr+d.s.display.x;
            var dyt = sin*htr+d.s.display.y;

            //clip source to circle radius too
            var dxs = cos*d.s.display.r+d.s.display.x;
            var dys = sin*d.s.display.r+d.s.display.y;

                var dx = d.t.display.x - d.s.display.x,
                dy = d.t.display.y - d.s.display.y;
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                return "M" + d.s.display.x + "," + d.s.display.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + dxt + "," + dyt;
        });
    }
}
```