# Integrating d3's fisheye plugin with a force layout tick function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to apply the fisheye effect to a force layout with collision detection, node dragging, zoom etc but am struggling to integrate a fisheye with my tick function.

The closest existing example I found was http://bl.ocks.org/bentwonk/2514276 but it doesn't really contain a custom tick function or enable the usual things like dragging a node while fisheye is applied.  For the sake of clarity, here's my tick function regardless of fisheye...

```
function tick(e) {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y;})

    node.each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))
        .each(collide(jitter)) 
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
}
```

And here's what I'm hoping to use on my svg listener to trigger fisheye...

```
svg.on("mousemove", function() {

    fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

    node
        .each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 8; });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.fisheye.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.fisheye.y; });
});
```

But when using both together I notice no fisheye effect - presumably tick() is overriding any changes from my svg listener (although even if I add force.stop() to my svg listener I still see no fisheye on the page or any console errors).

And of course if I replace the tick function, then the whole node layout won't compute properly to start with.

Apologies that I don't have a more specific question, but does anyone have any thoughts on the best way to approach combining these 2 behaviours so that I can use a fisheye effect without compromising on other force layout functionality?

Thanks!

EDIT:

My only thought so far is to simply use the svg listener to trigger the mouse position...

```
svg.on("mousemove", function() {
        //force.stop();
        fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));
});
```

And then have some kind of coordinate addition in the tick function...

```
node.each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))
            .each(collide(jitter)) 
            .each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })
            .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 8; })     
            .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                return "translate(" + d.x + d.fisheye.x + "," + d.y + d.fisheye.y + ")";
            });
```

(the above doesn't work though - just produces invalid coordinates so all nodes end up at the top-left of the screen)

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327176/d3-fisheye-on-a-force-graph-with-markers)?

Comment: Thanks Lars - I could be wrong, but that's specifically tackling the problem of fisheye for paths right?  The code contained in the answer that's responsible for positioning the nodes is just the same as my fisheye code above?  Looking at it I'd say it isn't aligned with any custom force tick - it's just that fisheye is being used as the ONLY thing that move nodes on tick?

Comment: Yes. In your case the two things are certainly interfering and it's not obvious to me how to combine them.

Comment: Thanks Lars.  I've made a quick edit describing the only idea for a solution that I've had so far - just in case it helps with other suggestions on a possible solution - or even a general approach to trying to tackle it.